# Preventing CSRF with implicit flow and JWTs?

Tags: cookies, oauth, csrf, openid-connect

I'm reading through [openid connect document](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect) ATM and it says:

> Put into a browser cookie the ID token can be used to implement lightweight stateless sessions.

IIUC we want to avoid using cookies in order to ensure avoid CSRF attacks, since the browser will send the cookie with all requests, and if the user loads an image (While logged in to notsosecurebank.com) with the URL:

```
href="http://notsosecurebank.com/transfer.do?acct=AttackerA&amount;=$100">Read more!
```

The browser will send the access token (Since it's a cookie) and this allows the attack to happen.

If the token is storage in session or local storage and only sent via REST / XHR requests, then there's no way for CSRF to happen?  Did I understand this correctly?